# If $A$ is a $*-$ Banach algebra then $\bar A^{wot} = \bar A^{weak^*}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

If $A$ is a $*-$ subalgebra of $B(H)$, then clearly $\bar A^{weak^*}\subset \bar A^{wot}$ (wot means weak operator topology). Also on every bounded subset of $A$, two topologies equal. Now my question is that could we show that $\bar A^{wot} = \bar A^{weak^*}$?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify meanings for me? In a $*$-Banach algebra, do you require the C$^*$-identity? What is the weak-star topology? It usually requires $A$ being a dual. What is the wot topology for a Banach algebra?

Comment: @MartinArgerami : I edited it. weak* topology is the topology $\sigma(B(H), B(H)_*)$ and  wot is the topology $\sigma(B(H) , F(H))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two closures are equal.

Let $x\in \bar A^{wot}$. We have $\bar A^{wot}=\bar A^{sot}$, so there is a net $\{x_j\}\subset A$ such that $x_j\to x$ sot. By Kaplansky, there is a bounded net $\{x_j'\}\subset A$ with $ x_j'\to x$ sot, and so wot. That is, $x$ belongs to the wot closure of a ball in $A$. But on balls, the wot and ultraweak topologies agree, which tells us that $x$ is the ultraweak limit of a net in $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer.